# Active Record Association without using id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I am not really sure that this hasn't been answered, but I am not sure what to search for so please point me in the right direction if I am asking something that is already answered.

I have 2 models:

stock_symbol and weight_symbol

stock_symbol has `symbol` in it which matches `commodity` in the weight_symbol model

How can I get an association to work so when I do stock_symbol.weight_symbol, I would get the weight_symbol back.

I know how to do this in SQL, but if its not the standard `id` to `this_id` then I am mostly lost.

edit:

```
class StockSymbol < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weight_symbols, primary_key: :symbol

  def commodity
    "LC" # This is just an example to simplify it, there is much more to this.
  end
end

class WeightSymbol < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stock_symbol, foreign_key: :commodity
end
```

Sample object from stock_symbol:

```
StockSymbol.last
<#StockSymbol id: 729, symbol: "LCJ13C12500", created_at: "2013-03-15 21:50:49", updated_at: "2013-03-15 21:50:49">
```

Sample object from weight_symbol:

```
WeightSymbol.first
<#WeightSymbol id:1, weight_group_id: 1, symbol: "LC", created_at: "2010-01-05 21:13:28", updated_at: "2010-01-05 21:13:28">
```

After setting this up and running `StockSymbol.last.weight_symbols.to_sql`  I get:

```
"SELECT `weight_symbols`.* FROM `weight_symbols` WHERE `weight_symbols`.`stock_symbol_id` = 'LCJ13C12500'"
```

edit 2:

Query that it should be doing (I think):

```
SELECT * FROM `weight_symbols` WHERE `weight_symbols`.`symbol` = 'LC';
```

Query to get the info that I want.

```
SELECT * FROM `weight_symbols` a
JOIN `stock_symbols` b
ON a.symbol = b.commodity
WHERE b.symbol = 'LCJ13C12500';
```

New Stock Symbol object

```
<#StockSymbol id: 729, symbol: "LCJ13C12500", created_at: "2013-03-15 21:50:49", updated_at: "2013-03-15 21:50:49", commodity: "LC">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rails association methods come with options to override the default keys used in the relationship. If it's a one to many association between `StockSymbol` and `WeightSymbol`, you use the following:

```
# stock_symbol.rb
has_many :weight_symbols, primary_key: :symbol

# weight_symbol.rb
belongs_to :stock_symbol, foreign_key: :commodity
```

(Not sure if I got the association the right way around, but you should get the idea.)

The [Detailed Association Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference) in the [Association Basics guid](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) has a thorough listing of all the options and methods belonging to each type of association.

---

**EDIT**: Some extra stuff based on your updated question.

I'm a little confused on how your association is supposed to work -- `WeightSymbol` doesn't seem to have a `commodity` attribute. Should a `WeightSymbol` be matched to its owning `StockSymbol` when the `weight_symbol.symbol == stock_symbol.commodity`? In that case, you need to set the keys accordingly:

```
# stock_symbol.rb
has_many :weight_symbols, primary_key: :commodity
# :primary_key is the field on this model whose value associated models will store in their foreign_key

# weight_symbol.rb
belongs_to :stock_symbol, foreign_key: :symbol
# :foreign_key is the column on this model that should match the primary_key field in the associated model
```

Secondly, you can only set up rails associations using database columns, you cannot use a method. If you absolutely must use a method, you could probably fake the association, for example using something like:

```
# stock_symbol.rb
def weight_symbol
  WeightSymbol.find_by_symbol(self.commodity)
end
```

The downside of this would be that it is horribly inefficient, and there would be a lot of reinventing the wheel involved.

If you have the option to make `commodity` a database field, that would possibly be the best solution, depending on how often it's likely to change. For example, if it's derived from the current state of the model, you could set up a `before_save` filter on the model to do whatever processing needs to happen and write the appropriate value to that field:

```
# stock_symbol.rb
before_save :set_commodity

def set_commodity
  commodity = "LC" # arrived at through whatever processing you do
  self.commodity = commodity
end
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  I may have something wrong.  I didn't think about it but commodity is a method instead of a column.  I hope there is still a way to do this.  I added everything I could think might help in the question.

Comment: Seems like there are a couple of issues based on that, and your updated question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I updated the database and added commodity as a column (I have no idea why I didn't do that before since it is really static information, so thank you for that).  I am still getting the same SQL output.  I am updating the original question with what I want in SQL format.  I don't understand enough about this to really get what I am doing wrong.  I read through the pages that you listed, but they didn't seem to show me the right example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I got it working with this: `has_many :weight_symbol, foreign_key: :symbol, primary_key: :commodity` in stock_symbol.rb. Can't get it to work the other way, but this will work.

Comment: I didn't realise `:foreign_key` was a valid option for `has_many` as well, so it makes sense. Not sure if you will also need to set the `:foreign_key` on the `belongs_to` association as well, but if things are working, it's all good right? Glad I could point you in the right direction.